# LED Strip - Wire Size & LED Controller

Tags: current, wire, led-strip

**First Question:**
I bought a few rolls of high density 5M individually adjustable LED strips - 14.4 Watts/M @ 24V which equals to 0.6A per meter.

I was advised I could run up to 10M in series which is 6A in total. But the LED strip came with a 22AWG (max 1A) wires for power transmission. Even running 5M would be 3A which is still well over 1A.

It's a short run yes but isn't it still a fire risk? Searched around but it seems everyone is generally OK with the thin wire that comes with LED strips.

So what am I missing here?

**Second Question:**
Does it matter if a LED controller connects data line in the middle of LED strip instead of the start/end of the LED strip? Reason being it's a staircase 21-steps LED strip run so sometimes the light effect should start from the bottom to the top when going up and vice versa from the top to the bottom when going down.

Comment: Data sheet is where?

Comment: Bought it off Chinese website so no datasheet available except for the few info i got from the seller. But these are general questions that i think can be answered without detailed datasheet

Comment: EEs of an experienced level don’t buy devices that don’t have a data sheet and not from sources whose reputation may be in doubt.